# How to push data and retrieve it using parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am writing a program which will work as a remote controller controlling another device.I am using parse cloud to push and retrieve data.
Now suppose I want to push a new command for the device Y from the device X.Then make a class commands in the parse cloud where there are three columns.

user1,user2,command

Now suppose I push a command "start Music Player" then I want to send this command to device Y from X.I am successful in saving this data over parse.Now what should I have to do if I want to retrieve this command as soon as possible on the device Y.I am not getting a single way to retrieve this command on device Y as soon as this command is pushed on the parse cloud.Should I have to program it on Cloud or I can make it possible in android app.Please explain with example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not inclined to write example code for you, but you can use a push notification to send the message to the second device.

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android

Click the Javascript button at the top if you want to see how to do it from cloud code.